# Is it possible to make a radio button de-selectable in JSP (like checkbox)

Tags: javascript, jsp

Is it possible to make a radio button de-selectable in JSP (like checkbox)?

I have a page with a coulmn of table having radio buttons. i want to de-select the radio button if i click it on selected radio. Here is the code

```
<tr>                    
<TD><INPUT type="radio" name="Radios" value="someValue"></td>
<TD>someValue</td>
</tr>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Radio buttons are not meant to be left blank - either provide a default - N/A option, or if all options may be unchecked, go with checkboxes.

See [first answer here](http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/13511/why-is-it-impossible-to-deselect-html-radio-inputs).

Answer (score 0):

You could use Javascript to  set/switch the attribute `checked` valued as `"checked"` (the button is selected) or `""` (empty stinrg = the button is not seleceted) based on mouse click events. Here is a [reference doc about radio buttons](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.radio.html).

Keep in mind that only one radio button in a group can be selected at a time.

Answer (score 0):

Try this javascript code:

```
var firstClick = true;
function tick(element){
 if(!firstClick){
     if(element.checked){
         element.checked = false;
         firstClick = true;
     }
 }else{
     firstClick = false;
 }

}
```

then add the onclick property

```
<tr>                    
<TD><INPUT type="radio" name="Radios" value="someValue" onclick="tick(this);"></td>
<TD>someValue</td>
</tr>
```

Note: This is not tested. But this should work.

Comment: It doesn't work because onchange handler fires before onclick so the button will be unchecked all the time. I think it's better to check the solution before posting it (it's not hard for JS). Also the parameter called "checked" not "selected".

Comment: Sorry. I forgot to consider the first click in the event. I edited the script and tested. This now works fine.

Comment: Much better! :) But there is an option when there are multiple buttons in radio group (having the same name). In this case all of them share the state determined by firstClick variable. I would suggest you to bind firstClick field to the button itself

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the unchecked button becomes checked right after the click before the onclick handler run. So even if the button was unchecked before the user clicks it it becomes checked when the handler is started. So the code below will not work.

```
function toggle(e)
{
    e.checked = !e.checked;
}
```

So there is a trick to avoid this issue. We just add a field which counts the parity of clicks.

```
function toggleRadioButton(e)
{
    if(e.parity==undefined)
    {
        e.parity = false;
    }
    e.parity = !e.parity;
    e.checked = e.parity;

    //Fix parity of other buttons of this group which are unchecked automatically
    if(e.checked)
    {
        var buttonsInGroup = document.getElementsByName(e.name);
        for(var i=0; i<buttonsInGroup.length; i++)
        {
            if(buttonsInGroup[i]!=e)
            {
                buttonsInGroup[i].parity = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

HTML part will have the standard onclick handler:

```
<INPUT type="radio" name="Radios" value="someValue" onclick="toggleRadioButton(this)"/>
```

However there may be some integrity issues when changing the state of the button programmatically. I really dislike this code but don't see any other solutions.

Finally my suggestion would be not to use radio buttons in this strange way :).